# Django Unit Tests - Changes to self properties are persisting from test to test

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

I have a test class that has a setup like this. We import a dictionary from a test_helpers file that has some default data. The data is set as `FORM_DATA['value_A'] = 0` and `FORM_DATA['value_B'] = 1000000` from the start.

Whether I set FORM_DATA to a self.form_data value, or assign it to a variable in each test, doesn't matter. The 2nd test seems to persist the dictionary changes from the 1st test, which is not ideal for testing.

I added a bunch of print debug statements to show what is happening. Even in the setUp() for the 2nd test, it shows the values from the previous test! What is happening here? Why can't the dictionary self.form_data be the default imported data every time I have a new test?

```
from test_helpers import FORM_DATA

class TestBaselineScenarios(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(TestBaselineScenarios, cls).setUpClass()
        long_running_data_setup()

    def setUp(self):
        self.form_data = FORM_DATA
        print("setUp", self.form_data['value_A'], self.form_data['value_B'])

    def test_one(self):
        print("1")
        print(self.form_data['value_A'], self.form_data['value_B'])
        self.form_data['value_A'] = 25000
        self.form_data['value_B'] = 700000
        print("2")
        print(self.form_data['value_A'], self.form_data['value_B'])
        simulation = test_helpers.create_simulation(form_data=self.form_data)
        simulation.run()
        self.assertEqual(0.8416667, round(simulation.success_rate(), 7))

    def test_two(self):
        print("3")
        print(self.form_data['value_A'], self.form_data['value_B'])
        self.form_data['value_A'] = 10000
        print("4")
        print(self.form_data['value_A'], self.form_data['value_B'])
        simulation = test_helpers.create_simulation(form_data=self.form_data)
        simulation.run()
        self.assertEqual(0.9916667, round(simulation.success_rate(), 7))
```

```
setUp 0 1000000
1
0 1000000
2
25000 700000


setUp 25000 700000
3
25000 700000
4
10000 700000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this code:

```py
self.form_data = FORM_DATA
```

you're not actually copying the contents of `FORM_DATA`, just storing a reference to it.
So, when you run `self.form_data['value_A'] = 25000`, you're also changing `FORM_DATA`.

Next time you run `setUp`, it's just assigning the same reference to the modified `FORM_DATA` back into `self.form_data`.

Try doing a copy of `FORM_DATA` instead.

Python has a couple of ways to create copies of things. Assuming `FORM_DATA` is a dict, the simplest is to call `dict.copy`. If it's more complex, you could also use the [built-in `copy` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) to create a *shallow copy*.

Change your setUp function to:

```py
    def setUp(self):
        self.form_data = FORM_DATA.copy()
        print("setUp", self.form_data['value_A'], self.form_data['value_B'])
```

Comment: That certainly worked, but geez, I thought the whole concept of the setUp was that it ran for every test, and thus would re-initialize the property. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @LaurenBoland it does! But (presumably for performance reasons) every test is run in the same instance of the Python interpreter. FORM_DATA exists only once globally per interpreter, so your later code was modifying FORM_DATA (via self.form_data), and then next time setUp ran, FORM_DATA remained modified.